# Android Retrofit + Moshi, retrieve nested data from response

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

If all API responses has the following structure:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "data": {
        // dynamic reponse object
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

My current retrofit object is using MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi). It is possible to use Moshi to just get the data within the data object, giving that this is the actual data I need to use?

Currently, my response object uses @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
and contains all the data, "status" and others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data classes like this

```
JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class SomeResponse(
        val status: String,
        val data: List<SomeData>,
        val others : List<OtherData>
)
JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class SomeData(
        val data1: String,
        val data2: String,
        ...
)
JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class OtherData(
        val otherData1: String,
        val otherData2: String,
        ...
)
```

Comment: But tbe SomeData Object is dynamic, it wouldn't work. Some of them are list, and other just string data. I want to create a data class Object per response, but i only need data, I don't want to make all responses to contain status and others.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a *polymorphic* adapter to handle different types that can be returned.

Check [the class built in to Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/adapters/PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.java) and try [this blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/moshi-polymorphic-adapter-is-d25deebbd7c5) for a walkthrough.